# limit the text length of angular-translate translation

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

Given the reference example of angular translate:

```
var app = angular.module('at', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

app.config(function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    TITLE: 'Hello',
    FOO: 'This is a paragraph.',
    BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'english',
    BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'german'
  });
  $translateProvider.translations('de', {
    TITLE: 'Hallo',
    FOO: 'Dies ist ein Paragraph.',
    BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'englisch',
    BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'deutsch'
  });
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $translate) {
  $scope.changeLanguage = function (key) {
    $translate.use(key);
  };
});
```

I want dynamically add a limitTo option which limits the length of the translation showed.

Lets say i have controller ctrl with variable x

> ctrl.x='FOO'

Then i have a html snippet

`<span translate="ctrl.x"></span>`

I would like somehow to write

```
<span translate="ctrl.x" limitTo=7>
```

and then the output would be

> This is

How do i accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

Comment: I though about this, but how do i plug in the filter? angular-translate can be used as a filter https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/04_using-translate-filter but just with string literals but not with variables

Comment: if you dont want to write another directive that wrap translate directive, may be use interpolation, `<span>{{ctrl.x|translate|limitTo:7}}</span>`

Comment: Have you considered using css to achieve the same end? `max-width: <number>em`, `overflow: hidden` and `text-overflow: hidden` may achieve what you want. If it needs to be dynamic, you could set the max-width element on the style attribute of the elements at runtime. I think this would be better than just clipping the translated result, anyway.